# How to populate data based on Pick list values in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

The following picture is a VF Page. I need to make mandatory Attachments if Catagory Field is "Seasonal Rotation Program" and Fss Rotation (Picklist) is "Advisory".

```
  if(caseRecord.ToD_Case_Category__c == 'Seasonal Rotation Program' && caseRecord.WCT_SubCategory2__c == 'Advisory'  && attachmentHelper.UploadedDocumentList.size() == 0)
     {

           pageErrorMessage = 'Attachment is required to submit the form.';
            pageError = true;
            return null;
        }
```

[image]

I have developed code for validation but I need to show and hide red colour star mark which indicates mandatory while those two fields data as above.

Should I write Action region and select option or any jQuery would work?

I am not able to achieve this. Can anyone please suggest me on this?

in Page:

```
<div id="attid">
           <dl class="col-2">
               <h4 class="subheader title">ATTACHMENTS</h4>
            </dl>
           <div class="row" >

           <dl class="col-2">
           <c:GBL_Attachments customLabel="Select File (Maximum Size: 25MB)" maxAllow="15" IdPrefix="sample"   globalAttachment="{!attachmentHelper}" validType="pdf,jpeg,jpg,docx,doc,.xls,xlsx,csv" id="attdiv">
            </c:GBL_Attachments>
           </dl>  
           </div>

           </div>
```

Comment: Can you add some of the code you already have written. It would help to see code you have already written.

Comment: Just updated question with code. I just need front end to show or hide red star mark

Comment: Are you using standard visualforce tags or are you using HTML tags to create the page?

Comment: Both Standard vf tags and HTML tags

Comment: I would suggest looking at this link: http://www.minerva18.com/blog/using_jquery_in_salesforce_visualforce/ as well as looking into this one for more about what you can do in jquery: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp They should get you started in the right direction.